# Is anyone using Steinberg's HALion for Sound Design?

Tags: sampler, cubase, daw, steinberg, radio

I've always tended to layer sounds on a DAW timeline, but am wanting to jump into the sampler world for some of my work.  This way I can come up a palette of basic sounds I create by category, and they 'style' those sounds and build on top of them based on the library I'm working on at the time (I make sounds for several radio imaging libraries and networks).

Also, I spend a lot of time just 'messing around' with synths and audio processors in real time, recording the results to a new file.  Taking the time to go back and chop through those long files to find useful material gets very old, and the concept of chopping up longer files in a sampler, or setting start and stop play markers for only the bits of audio I respect seems like a no-brainer.

For most projects I use Cubase (version 6 is amazing!).  HALion is, of course, very compatible, and lets you drag in Cubase regions directly, uses all the Steinberg plugins I'm familiar with, comes with a decent factory library, etc...  Very appealing.

But, I wanted to see if anyone out there on SSD is using HALion specifically for sound design, and could offer any pros / cons.

By the way, I've been reading questions / answers on this site for a few months, but this is my first post.  I've learned so much!  SSD is now one of my daily addictions (now if I could just cut out smoking and caffeine!).